# Copying files to embedded linux (WRT54GL)

Tags: uart, busybox

I have a shell over UART on a WRT54GL. I'd like to copy files to and from it.

It has a very stripped back linux OS. It does not have tftp running, netcat or wget either.

Are there any other ways i could send a file over UART directly?

Comment: Use zmodem protocol (the package usually is called `lrzsz` also part of Busybox.